# Pandas adding new columns according to past durations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which is

| DURATION | feature_x |
| --- | --- |
| 202004 | value_a |
| 202003 | value_b |
| 202002 | value_c |
| 202001 | value_d |

I want to append table with parametric history field like as;

| DURATION | feature_x | feature_x_t1 | feature_x_t2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202004 | value_a | value_b | value_c |
| 202003 | value_b | value_c | value_d |
| 202002 | value_c | value_d | Nan |
| 202001 | value_d | Nan | Nan |

At that point, I could not find a appropriate solution. Is there any solution or suggestion ?

Comment: I need to find a general solution for big dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shift`:

```
df['feature_x_t1'] = df['feature_x'].shift(-1)
df['feature_x_t2'] = df['feature_x'].shift(-2)

df
```

Output:

```
   DURATION feature_x feature_x_t1 feature_x_t2
0    202004   value_a      value_b      value_c
1    202003   value_b      value_c      value_d
2    202002   value_c      value_d          NaN
3    202001   value_d          NaN          NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for loop` and [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) method for this:

```
for x in range(1,len(df)+1):
    df['feature_x_t'+str(x)]=df['feature_x'].shift(-x)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get:

```
    DURATION    feature_x   feature_x_t1    feature_x_t2    feature_x_t3    feature_x_t4
0   202004      value_a     value_b         value_c         value_d         NaN
1   202003      value_b     value_c         value_d         NaN             NaN
2   202002      value_c     value_d         NaN             NaN             NaN
3   202001      value_d     NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN
```

Comment: If you wish, please consider accepting the answer to signal others that the issue is resolved...Thanks **:)**